# High current consumption in STOP MODE of STM32L496ZG MCU on an STM32-Nucleo board (Nucleo-144, MB1312)

Tags: power, stm32, embedded

I'm using Nordic's Power Profiler Kit II to measure current of STM32L496ZG MCU on STM32 Nucleo board. I've tried to measure current using JP5 (IDD) as mentioned in the datasheet but current consumption is too high (163uA) considering the fact that I'm using tickless idle mode example (freertos low power).

I've been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSLN_WM2TOc&t=929s&ab_channel=STMicroelectronics

As far as connections are concerned, I've connected Vin of PPK II to one pin and Vout to other pin of JP5 of Nucleo board. I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: You should add information that demonstrates the engineering needed to monitor the current. Posting a link to a video will render your question broken should the link fail or the video move or become deleted (out of your control) so, add what you need to add to the question above.

Comment: Disconnect all peripherals and external connection and run program which just switches desired low power mode and never wake up. This eliminates bugs in software as well as parastics consumptions caused by hardware. Do you get expected power consumption? Then try adding recently removed parts one by one and see what cause issue. We have very limited options to determine source. It may be configuration, software or hardware issue.